# display two charts with IE

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I can't display 2 charts with IE while it works with Chrome and FF. Only one chart is displayed. Here my code :

```
function pie() {    
$('#pie_projet').highcharts({
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Nombre de projet ANRU par communes'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                connectorColor: '#000000',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '8px',
                    color: 'black'
                },
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y}'                    
            }
        }           
    },
    colors: [<?php echo join($tabSliceColor,',') ?>],
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Nb projet',
        //document.getElementsByName(data_pie)[0].value
        data: [<?php echo join($data_pie, ',') ?>]
    }]

});
};

function groupBar() {   
$('#bar_projet').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Nombre d\'opérations par année et par type d opérations ANRU'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Valenciennes Métropole'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [<?php echo join($legend_bar,',') ?>],
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            style: {
                fontSize: '9px'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: [{
        min: 0,
        max: 200,
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: 'red'
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Nombre total d\'opérations',
            align: 'middle'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        },                
        opposite: true
    },
    // second yAxis
    {
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        labels:{
            style :{
                color: 'red'
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Nombre d\'opérations',
            align: 'middle'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        }
    }],
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' opérations'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 50,
        y: 60,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        shadow: true,
        itemStyle: {
            color: 'black', 
            fontSize: '7px'
        }
    },
    colors: [<?php echo join($tabOpColor,',') ?>],
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            animation: false
        },
        spline: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    crop : false // permet de ne pas bloquer l'affichage d'un label si hot
                }
        }
    },
    series: [<?php echo join($series_bar,',') ?>,<?php echo $line_data?>]       
});
```

};

I call the 2 fonctions like this :

```
<BODY onLoad ='pie();groupBar();'>
```

The charts are put in DIV :

```
<div id='bar_projet' style='min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto'></div>
<div id='pie_projet' style='min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto'></div>
```

With IE I see only one chart , the second one and with Chrome and FF I see both of them.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Check the console for any errors?

Comment: How your data looks like? any errors? could you prepare this example as jsfiddle with hardcoded data?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried initialising it on load using jquery instead of in the body onLoad ?

```
$(function () {
    pie();
    groupBar();
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried but It is the same. I tried on another computer with IE 10 and it works ! So I don't know why it's not working with IE 9

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs only in IE and not in any other browser right??? Using inspector check the id of the tags associated with your chart they are probably repeating (for example check your loading div's id) that is where I usually make my mistake.

It is because IE goes nuts when two tags have the same id.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your help... so it is crazy ! I tried on another computer with IE 10  and it works and still not work on my computer with IE 9. The loadind div id have not the same id !